# this.date.trim is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am filtering by date, but such an error occurs:

> ERROR TypeError: this.date.trim is not a function

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="di" [(ngModel)]="date" placeholder="Date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="di"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #di></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
  date = "";

  applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.date ? this.date.trim().toLowerCase() : '';
  }
```

Comment: Trim works with string, not date

Comment: `trim` is a `String` method, not a `Date` one.

Comment: what is the use of `trim` here there will be no whitespace on any side of the date selected by the datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Convert your date to string, then use `trim()`.

like,

```
date: Date;
applyFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = this.date ? this.date.toString().trim().toLowerCase() : '';
  }
```

> But you should pass date type of value to the filter property instead of string. Then only the filter will works Perfectly.